# How to set tensorflow gpu memory allocation outside of my code?

Tags: apache-spark, memory, tensorflow, gpu

I am using tensorflow on the spark.
my tensorflow allocates almost all GPU memory ( 10GB or 12GB).
only 'import tensorflow' take all memory
I know how to configure gpu memory fraction inside the code. The way I know is to add the code mentioned below

```
import tensorflow as tf
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.2)
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))
```

BUT.. On the spark, Even though I add this congifuration in the code, It cannot be applied to other GPU machines..
So, I want to know how to configure or set up the gpu fraction outside of the code, which means by tensorflow itself..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At tensorflow/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc
Change from

```
if (config_memory_fraction == 0) {
allocated_memory = available_memory;
```

to

```
if (config_memory_fraction == 0) {
allocated_memory = total_memory * 0.2(fraction u want to use);
```

After then, BUILD it by bazel.

It is kinda hardcoding.
If u modify source code, u can do dynamic allocation of gpu memory